# Adding and printing arrays

Tags: java, arrays

In this program I want to:

-transfers history looks like: "1 -3000", "2 300"

-when I add transfer I want to program backs to first choose menu

What I did wrong? My begginer mind tells me that should working... but won't.

```
package ejavakurs1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class printF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] bankTransfer = new int[100];

        Scanner skaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
              .print("1 - Show history\n2 - Add Bank Transfer\n3 - End\n Choose: ");
        int a = skaner.nextInt();

        do {
            switch (a) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(bankTransfer);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Type Bank Transfer: ");
                    int b = skaner.nextInt();
                    for (int i = 0; i < bankTransfer.length; i++) {
                        bankTransfer[i + 1] = b;
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    break;
            }
        } while (a == 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I think your program wants to do is to make some kind of history of changes, right? I would suggest not using an `Int[]` but a `List<Integer>` where you can just append changes without the manual handling of the index.

Comment: ok, I will check "list<integer>", now I didn't used this because in exercise I have to use basic arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your loop to continue until 3 it typed, you should change

```
while (a==3)
```

to

```
while (a!=3)
```

In addition, `bankTransfer[i+1]= b;` will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. It should be `bankTransfer[i]= b;`

Comment: The `for` loop for case 2 also has problems.

Answer (score 0):

make it like

```
while(a!=3);
```

because you want to repeat it until the value is not 3.

Comment: Why exactly do you repeat an answer given 3 minutes ago?